# androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group not working with setTranslationY

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

does anyone has any idea why androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
does not work with setTranslationY.
Thank you in advance with help.

```
Group groupAppList = fragmView.findViewById(R.id.group_app_list);

backgr = fragmView.findViewById(R.id.choose_app_backgr);
groupAppList.setTranslationY(metrics.heightPixels);
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the documentation for `Group`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Group):

> This class controls the visibility of a set of referenced widgets... The visibility of the group will be applied to the referenced widgets. It's a convenient way to easily hide/show a set of widgets without having to maintain this set programmatically.

You cannot apply arbitrary attributes to `Group`, whether in layout XML or programmatically.